# Java matching a string with wildcard regex to find <H1> tags

Tags: java, html, regex, html-parsing

I have several HTML files, each has a single `<h1>` tag in it. I want to parse that tag to get it's content (a name of a book). A tag looks like this for example:

```
<H1>bookname</H1>
```

I am trying to get it using this code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file, "Windows-1255");
String name="";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<H1>*</H1>"); //tried adding '(' and ')' around the '*', didn't help
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    name = scan.nextLine();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
    if (m.matches()) {
        name = name.substring(4, name.length() - 6);
        break;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, the h1 tag is never matched and I don't get the name.
How is this supposed to be done?

Perhaps it's important, the contents of the H1 tags are in Hebrew, charset=Windows-1255.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<H1>.*</H1>`?

Comment: don't parse HTML with regex, use a library like jtidy or jsoup instead

Comment: @ChrisW shouldn't it be `<H1>.*?</H1>`!

Comment: u r trying to cut a `tree(html)` with a `knife(regex)`..although it would work but is knife made to cut a tree..use a `saw(html parser)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<H1>.*</H1>");
```

(notice the extra `.` - your version matches just empty  tags).

Comment: Thanks @Dan Berindei. By the way, I did try \w* but it was interpreted by the compiler as a non-existing escape character. How would I look for letters only?

Comment: u r trying to cut a `tree(html)` with a `knife(regex)`..although it would work but is knife made to cut a tree..use a `saw(html parser)`

Comment: @Fake, your answer is very unclear. I believe you are using a terminology I don't know. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @Dan Berindei - \\w* didn't work for me but it's OK, I'm using .* and it works perfectly because the <H1> tags does not contain any non-letter characters anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I found an example that might work for you.
It simplifies and generalizes also the matching procedure so you don't need to substring your found pattern:

```
String stringToSearch = "<h1>Yada yada yada yada </h1>";
String name = "";

// the pattern we want to search for
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<h1>.*</h1>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);

// if we find a match, get the group 
if (m.find())
{
  // get the matching group
  name = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, the \\s+ is the regex for white spaces, not a wild card. But this makes it clear why my \w* didn't work, I guess I should have used \\w* instead. Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: It's the opposite, a non-whitespace character.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: To make it clearer, `\s` is a space, and `\S` is everything except a whitespace.

Comment: Also, in Java `\w` means `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, so it is not equivalent to `\S'.

Comment: `/<h1>(\S+)</h1>/i` does not work as described. It will match: `<h1>AllOneWord</h1>` but will fail to match: `<h1>This has spaces</h1>`.